# Multiplying using a CFG

Tags: math, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I am trying to make a CFG that is equivalent the function below. I know that B is the loop counter so it could be a series of elements pushed onto a stack, every time the loop is completed an element from B is popped and if B = Epsilon quit. How do I handle the addition in the top half of the while loop?

```
PROCEDURE multiply a, b;
VAR a, b, z;
BEGIN
z := 0;
  WHILE b > 0 DO BEGIN
        z := a + z;
        b := b - 1;
  END
  RETURN z;
END;
```

Comment: How can you make a CFG equivalent to a function, when a CFG has no input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do that with a CFG, although you could certainly do it with a CSG. The pumping lemma should suffice to prove impossibility.

If `b` is fixed, though, it's easy:

```
S ⇒ ε
S ⇒ 0 S 1 1 … 1
       (b times)
```

That will recognize strings of the form

```
0a1a·b
```

which is the only sense I can think of in which a CFG can implement multiplication.

Comment: Oh, so there isn't a stack frame I would have to preserve or something like a PDA?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: The stack of a PDA is pretty limited. You only ever have access to the top; once you pop that, it's gone. So the concept of stack frames doesn't make any sense in this context.